# Requirements for Any in antlr4

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to writer a visitor for a simple grammar with Antlr4, but I'm having trouble getting my types cast into the `Any` types that the generated grammar uses.

As a minimal example, my types are

```
class Atom {
public:
  Atom(int idx, std::string el) : index(idx), element(el) {}
  int index;
  std::string element;
};
```

The visitor functions in my parser work just fine if I pass pointers.

```
 antlrcpp::Any MyVisitor::visitSpecies(DissolveParser::SpeciesContext *context) {
  auto terms = context->speciesTerm();

  for (auto &term : terms) {
    Atom* temp = visit(term);
    std::cout << "Atom " << temp->element << " " << temp->index << std::endl;
  }

  return true;
}


antlrcpp::Any MyVisitor::visitSpeciesAtom (DissolveParser::SpeciesAtomContext *context) {
    int index = std::stoi(context->index->getText());
    std::string element = visit(context->element);
    Atom* result = new Atom(index, element);
    antlrcpp::Any finalResult(result);
    return finalResult;
}
```

However, I don't want to pass around pointers, but rather values.  However, this causes a crash

```
    antlrcpp::Any MyVisitor::visitSpecies(DissolveParser::SpeciesContext *context) {
      auto terms = context->speciesTerm();

      for (auto &term : terms) {
        Atom temp = visit(term);
        std::cout << "Atom " << temp.element << " " << temp.index << std::endl;
      }

      return true;
    }


antlrcpp::Any MyVisitor::visitSpeciesAtom (DissolveParser::SpeciesAtomContext *context) {
    int index = std::stoi(context->index->getText());
    std::string element = visit(context->element);
    Atom result(index, element);
    antlrcpp::Any finalResult(result);
    return finalResult;
}
```

This crashes with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'`.  What does the `Atom` type need to be cast into an `Any`?

Comment: Which line causes the bad_cast to be thrown? Since the `Any` class is header only you should be able to set a breakpoint on the line where the bad_cast exception is thrown, to examine what is stored and to which it is casted.

Comment: The exception occurs on the `Atom temp = visit(term)` line.  Unfortunately, gdb isn't giving me much help here, since there's no named value to inspect.  I can confirm that `visitSpeciesAtom` seems to return without issue, but I can't seem to inspect the `Any` value it returns.  I've tried explicitly returning an `Any` and then casting that value to an `Atom`, but gdb just tells me that the compiler has optimized out the intermediate (despite not intentionally activating any optimization).

Comment: Any uses type erasure with an inner type, which makes this tricky to inspect. There's only [one line](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/support/Any.h#L152) throwing the `bad_cast` exception. Try to do this check (the dynamic cast) yourself to see what goes wrong there.